# Keeping unused elements?

Tags: 6

I keep a lot of unused elements that I don't bother to delete such as blocks, content types, views, taxonomies etc. Is there any speed benefit of deleting these unused elements? If so which ones?

Comment: About which ones to delete, just remove the ones you don't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could help, yes. Your site will be faster, and easier to manage.

- less elements means Drupal uses less memory
- with less elements, it takes less time to read them all (unused elements are still active)